# Unknown reason for "Expected ':'" error in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following function defined in my site.  It works for some people, not for others.  The exception occurs on the last line in the method, where the concatenation is.  I believe that because url's question mark character designating the query string is being looked as a ternary operator.

Is there something here that I'm not seeing, or is there a better way to build this string?

The url variable has a value of : "mywebpage.aspx?AccountNumber=123456"

```
function popUp(url) {
    var myleft = (screen.width) ? (screen.width - 750) / 2 : 100;
    var   mytop = (screen.height) ? (screen.height - 300) / 2 : 100;
    var id = new Date().getTime();

    eval("page" + id + " = window.open(" + url + ", '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=900,height=325, top='" + mytop + "',left='" + myleft +");");
}
```

Comment: You need to wrap the `url` in `'` so javascript knows it's a string.

Comment: You don't need to do this with `eval()`, and as in any case involving `eval()` that means you *shouldn't* do it with `eval()`.

Comment: Off topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll eliminate the "quotes within quotes" problem by avoiding `eval()`:

```
window["page" + id] =
    window.open(url, id, 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=900,height=325, top=' + mytop + ',left=' + myleft);
```

You should also make sure you use an "id" value that serves as a valid identifier (starts with a non-digit character, specifically) or else Internet Explorer will throw an error.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to put single quotes before and after closing and opening double quotes around url variable? Somthing like:

```
 ..." = window.open('" + url + "',...
```

Answer (score 0):

use `encodeURIComponent(url)` instead of using pure url in `window.open`

This function encodes special characters. In addition, it encodes the following characters: , / ? : @ & = + $ #

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp)

Comment: I'm not sure this addresses the actual issue.

Comment: Agreed. This should be a comment